# Identify this connector for my irrigation system

Tags: identification, irrigation, drip-system

Two years ago I had an irrigation system installed in my garden; now I'd like to expand it with a drip line.

The man who installed the system left a tube specifically for this purpose, and today I unearthed it; the problem is that I don't know the name of the connector I need, and also I was unable to remove the cap that is closing the tube.

I don't want to apply excessive force to avoid breaking the tube. I tried unscrewing the black part from the blue one, turning the cap counterclockwise.

Is this the right way to do it? Is the cap simply stuck since it was buried for two years? Do I need special tools or would a couple of wrenches do the trick?

(Note: the tube isn't under pressure, there's a valve on the other end.)

Also, shops are closed due to Covid-19 (I'm in Italy); what kind of conector should I search for on Amazon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compression fitting. The blue ring unscrews, a couple of wrenches on it and the black nut will be fine. For future fittings you need to identify the pipe size and material.

Comment: Success! With two wrenches (and without fear of breaking anything) the cap came off; now I can measure the pipe size and proceed with my project. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if inside out outside diameter is used in your area for describing pipes.